# Super and import in python

Tags: python, import, super

What are the differences between importing a class from a file and using super() in python?

Import: # I understand that this will import all the functions and **init** from a class to another class in a file when trigger the below code;

```
from something import Some
```

super(): # I understand that this also will inherit all the functions and **init** from a class to another class in a file. **Ain't this technically the same as importing?

```
super(xx, self).__init__() or super().__init__() or super()
```

Can any python experts shows some example? I have recently read some codes online and they used both of this, my question is since both do almost the same thing(to　my understanding) then why dont just use either one for all files and why need to use both? If possible, can share some examples?

Comment: they are totally different ... as in not at all the same thing or even similar ... I don't understand how you think they are the same thing... super is used inside of a classes methods to call methods on its parent classes ... import is to import a module

Comment: Yea, but from what I understand, we can still import the module form file B into file A and in file A we can still use the methods from the file B in file A right? Then what makes it different than super() which calls the methods from file B when used in file A? Please explain a little if possible.

Comment: A module is not a class, and functions in a module are not methods! You *cannot* use ``super`` to do the same as ``import``, because the former works on classes and the later on modules.

Answer (score 0):

`import` is used for importing module
`__init__()` is a class `method`, which is invoked when a new instance of a class is instantiated
This is 2 different thing

EDIT: I've made this edit to clarify the answer for you, since I assume you are not familiar with OOP. TL;DR: These two terms are completely different, they relate to two separate things. `super()` call a class's parent method, while `import` import a module

> we can still import the module form file B into file A and in file A
>   we can still use the methods from the file B in file A right?

Right.

> what makes it different than super() which calls the methods from file B when used in file A

First, you only encounter `super()` in `subclass` (lets say class B) of a `class`(lets say class A). You access A's method through B's `instance` via `super()`. Let see this example: You have 2 file, `A.py` and `B.py`, each define `A` and `B`:

In A.py, you define class `A`

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Instantiate class A")

    def printA(self):
        print("AAAAAAAAAAAAAA")
```

In B.py, you define class `B`:

```
from A import A  # you need this import for `B.py` to know what is `A`

class B(A): # Mean B inherit A
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__() # This line all its parent's method (`__init__()`)

    def printB(self):
        print("BBBBBBBBBBBB")

        super(B, self).printA()  # This line all its parent's method (`printA`)

# And you instantiate a `B` instance, then call a method of it, which call its super method `printA`
b = B()
b.printB()
```

Output is (note that `**init**():

> Instantiate class A
>   BBBBBBBBBBBB
>   AAAAAAAAAAAAAA

To conclude, I suggest you to read some material about OOP. You will clearly see the differences btw these two things. Good luck. I hope this help!

Comment: My same question to the above comment. Yea, but from what I understand, we can still import the module form file B into file A and in file A we can still use the methods from the file B in file A right? Then what makes it different than super() which calls the methods from file B when used in file A? Please explain a little if possible.

Comment: Aint it better to just use from fileA import fileB and inside file A we just use the self.function(which supposed to be in File B) and still running

Comment: I've made an edit for my answer, please read it and let me know if you still have problem

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to understand a bit of Object-oriented programming principles to understand `super`.

In general, when you are importing a module, that module becomes available for your current function/class.

By using `Super` you satisfy inheritance; facilitating your current class's `this` to have references to all attributes of its parent(s). If you are just developing some functions, you will not need `super`. This is strictly an object-oriented paradigm.

```
from xyz import abc

def some_function():
    # here you can use abc's attributes by explicit invocation.
    x = abc.x

    # Or call functions.
    abc.some_function()
```

When you're dealing with classes, `super` does the magic of facilitating inheritance.

```
class Parent_Class(object):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Parent_Class, self).__init__()

    def parent_method(self):
        print('This is a parent method')


class Child_Class(Parent_Class):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Child_Class, self).__init__()

    def child_method(self):
        # Because of super, self of child class is aware of all its parent's methods and properties.
        self.parent_method()
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation but may I ask? What about if we have a class from another file and one class in another file? Aint just using import will import everything including the functions and attributes from first file? Example, from fileA import A within "file B". From there, we can use x = A.x or A.somefunction(). So what about this? Is the super does something different or extra on top of import when involving two different files with separate classes. From many examples, I seen all classes are within the same python file and not different file.

Comment: Also, isnt it just good enough to put super in Child_Class only? Why also in Parent_Class? Sorry I am still learning so I wanted to clear my misunderstanding

Comment: Import and super are two different things altogether. Please read and understand inheritance and some basics of OOPS. There are plenty of resources available.

Comment: You'll need `super` in every class. Should you not do this, `MRO` will hurt you down the line.

Comment: @ohmygodiamnewbie, accept answer if it has helped your understanding. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `import` statement is used to import modules into modules. The `super` callable is used to delegate from subclass implementation to superclass implementation.

Notably, `import` connects between fixed equals whereas `super` connects in a dynamic hierarchy.

---

The point of `import` is to make a specific module or its content available in another module.

```
# moda.py
def foo(who):
    print(who, "called '%s.foo'" % __name__)

# modb.py
import moda
moda.foo(__name__)
```

Note that importing uses a qualified name that *uniquely identifies* the target. At any time, the name used in an `import` can refer to only one specific entity. That means that `import` couples strongly - the target is fully identified and cannot change after the `import`.

---

The point of `super` is to access the closest superclass implementation in a subclass implementation.

```
class A:
    def call(self, who):
        print(who, "called '%s.call'" % __class__, "on self of class", self.__class__)

class Alpha(A):
    def call(self, who):
        super(Alpha, self).call(who)
        print("... via '%s.call'" % __class__)
```

Note that `super` only work with local information - `super` does only identify the source, not the target. As such, the target is dynamically bound and not uniquely identifiable. That means that `super` couples weakly - the target is *relatively* defined and can only be resolved at runtime.

```
class Alpher(A):
    def call(self, who):
        print("'%s.call' sneakily intercepts the call..." % __class__)
        super(Alpher, self).call(who)

class Better(Alpha, Alpher):
     pass
```

The above injects `Alpher` into the relation from `Alpha` to `A` without modifying either of the two.

```
>>> Better().call('Saul')
'<class '__main__.Alpher'>.call' sneakily intercepts the call...
Saul called <class '__main__.A'>.call on self of class <class '__main__.Better'>
...via '<class '__main__.Alpha'>.call'
```